# bool isItem(TextAsset f) always returns false

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The following script is something I've started working on, it takes a TextAsset and splits the lines and compares it to a variety of strings. However my check functions are only returning false. Is there something major I'm missing, Unity isn't throwing any errors so I'm not sure what to do to fix this.

```
    internal sealed class Checker {
        private string AssetType(TextAsset fileToBeChecked) {
            string[] line = fileToBeChecked.text.Split (new char[] { '\n' });
            return line [0];
        }
        public bool isItem(TextAsset file) {
            string type = AssetType (file).ToLower ();
            if (type == "helmet" || type == "cuirass" || type == "gauntlets" || type == "gloves" || type == "boots" || type == "leggings" || type == "shield" || type == "robes" || type == "shirt" || type == "pants" || type == "shoes" || type == "hood" || type == "staff" || type == "stave" || type == "sword" || type == "greatsword" || type == "dagger" || type == "mace" || type == "warhammer" || type == "axe" || type == "waraxe" || type == "bow" || type == "misc") {
                return true;
            } else {            
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My test file is below:

```
Helmet
1
Dragon's Vale
0
10
0
14
1280
```

After Debugging

[Debug Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jk43G.png)

Comment: Well, what is `type` when you debug it?

Comment: This should be easily disvovered using the debugger. We can´t know what `AssetType(file).ToLower()` returns as we don´t know your context. So how should we know why the condiditions never pass?

Comment: @EvanTrimboli the file containing the info states helmet and when I had the function give me the value after pulling it it said helmet. but when it compared to "helmet" it returned false.

Comment: @HimBromBeere I will post the test file I am using to give context to the value of `AssetType(file).toLower()`.

Comment: Case doesn't match.

Comment: helmet != Helmet.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli That´s why OP used `ToLower`.

Comment: What is `type` when you run the debugger?

Comment: Once again: debug your code and see what `type` contains. You may post a screenshot of the debugger having the value as well. However I assume there are characters witin your file (such as spaces) that you don´t see in the debugger, making `"helmet   " != "helmet"`.

Comment: type = helmet when I run the debugger.

Comment: It's obviously not, otherwise it would be matching.

Comment: Please only post the code that is needed to reproduce the problem. It seems that isEnchantment() and isSpell() are irrelevant and can be removed.

Comment: In addition to what Tomas mentions you can also remove the file-content from the post. Only the actual content of `type` at runtime is interesting here, not how `type` was extracted.

Comment: @HimBromBeere I will remove IsEnchantment and isSpell, but I'm not certain that my issue isn't in how type was extracted.

Comment: What is the length of `type`?

Comment: @EvanTrimboli it should be 6 but it is registering 7, but there are no leading or trailing characters, newlines, or spaces. I added new text before the debug text and after and there are no spaces.

Comment: Split the file by `System.Environment.NewLine`

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, and I'm not sure why, but adding Trim() to my ToLower() fixed that problem but I didn't see it because another error in the same file was preventing me from properly comparing the values. I have fixed both issues though I don't know why Trim fixed my issue when there were no values before or after my type string. No matter, the script is working as intended.

the fixed code is:

```
private string AssetType(TextAsset fileToBeChecked) {
    string[] line = fileToBeChecked.text.Split (new char[] { '\n' });
    return line [0].Trim ();
}
```

Comment: If you add the altered line so others can find the answer quicker that would be great, i.e. show the bit of fixed code